# Notes 6: Why do OutOfOffice agents work for Editor level users but not Manager level users?

Tags: email-server, lotus-notes

A bunch of our users have started complaining that their OutOfOffice agents aren't working. After some investigating, it looks to me that all the people with the issue have manager permissions to their mailbox. Testing it confirms that mere Editor permissions users all have the correct "On Behalf Of" and "Allow Changes by users" boxes filled when reviewing the agent in designer. But manager level users have both those sections empty. By filling those in manually for the users, the OOO works, but I'm trying to figure out what it is that fills those in for the Editor users that won't do it for the Manager users. We are on Notes 6.0.2CF1. (I know, super old, but this is all orders from on high aka parent company)

Anyway, if anyone has any idea on how to make sure the Manager level users are able to have OutOfOffice agents work properly with minimal intervention, I'm all ears! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the OOO-Agent Diagnostic tool. It fixes 99% of OOA issues and offers help on resolving items.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21296389

Comment: It's for R7, so I am not sure how helpful it will be (R6 is pretty old), but worth running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in an environement where I can test this stuff anymore... But where I used to work it was Notes6.5

Typically I would try to copy the NOTES.INI from a working client to a failing client. If that failed, try replacing the some of the client side files (I don't remember then anymore .. desktop.dsk??? etc) and if that failed to try refresh/replace the design.

This assumes actual permissions are OK. This assumes that both are using the same design etc.. and that other agents are working.